# Lower limit for the 'number-of-concurrent-operations' parameter and 'minimum network bandwidth required' in AzCopy

Tags: azure, azcopy

We are trying to implement a wrapper around AzCopy that will be running in a low network bandwidth environment. However we could not find clear cut information around the minimum bandwidth required for AzCopy to function and if there is a lower limit on the number-of-concurrent-operations parameter.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the environment variable AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE to "AUTO". That helps a lot in low-bandwidth cases, since it results in AzCopy using far fewer connections that normal. (This is often enough on its own to fix low-bandwidth issues)
2. You can also give AzCopy an explicit speed cap, by adding something like this to the command line: --cap-mbps 10
   (Choose a reasonable figure for your environment)
3. If (and only if) you have low bandwidth, you have multiple files in each AzCopy job, and you need to use azcopy jobs resume to resume failed jobs, then set the environment variable AZCOPY_CONCURRENT_FILES.  Set it to 1 if your files are big, or to about 4 or 8 if they are small. (The default is 64. Reducing it will mean each failed job has fewer files in-flight at the time of the failure, which will is good when resuming).

As for changing the block size.  I’ve never actually recommended that. There is a --block-size-mb parameter.  I suppose a smaller block size could make operations more likely to succeed when retried.  But the steps above usually work, so changing the block size is not usually needed.  And also, for files bigger than a few 10’s of GB, you can’t actually force the smallest possible size because, if you do, you exceed Azure’s block count limit.  So it’s probably easier just to leave the block size alone and let AzCopy set it automatically.

AzCopy does a good job of using the available bandwidth.  I.e. that portion of the physically installed bandwidth, which is not already in use by other traffic.  For the purposes of calculations, with network speeds up to 5Gbps, I’d suggest you assume it will use 90% of the available bandwidth.  If you have disks and network that are even faster than that, then you’d need to transfer at least two files in parallel to fill the network (since we currently usually don’t manage to get more than about 5 Gbps on a single file).